# service app stop after running a script.sh

Tags: bash, docker-compose, dockerfile, sh

I have a container that has a serivce app, that is built with a dockerfile.

```
services:
   app:
      build: docker
```

Inside my docker file i have at the end, a script.sh that i run to initialize drupal and databases

```
COPY script.sh /sh/script.sh
RUN chmod +x /sh/script.sh
CMD /sh/script.sh

WORKDIR /var/www
```

Inside my script.sh i have this

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
php ./web/vendor/bin/drush cim -y &
wait
php ./web/vendor/bin/drush cr &
wait
exit 0
```

Everything works just fine the problem i have is that the service app stop right after it clear and rebuilt the cache. The problem is everytime I start the service app again it runs the dockerfile which run the script.sh to finally stop the service again
So if anyone have a solution to this on why it does this and how to make so that the service doesn't stop when it finish the script.sh

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your entrypoint, put a command that will prevent the container from quitting, i.e.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

php ./web/vendor/bin/drush cim -y
php ./web/vendor/bin/drush cr

tail -f -s5 /dev/null
```